# How to put form validation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have form like below,

```
<div ng-if="vm.settingsObj.others.name === 'Course Specialization'">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="specialization in vm.settingsObj.course_specialization">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-8" >
                            <input name="course_specialization{{$index}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Specialization" ng-model="specialization.value" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                            <button  ng-click="vm.removeStatus('course_specialization',$index)" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="vm.addStatus('course_specialization')" >ADD</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here i am incrementing the input field when i click on 'Add' button but when i leave input fields as empty and click on save it is getting saved.So what i need is form validation when my field is empty.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap all inputs in a single form tag so that you can use angular form validation. Angular provides a well set of validations using classes and form controller and you should go for that. For more information you can find a reference from below links:

[link one](http://[1]:%20http://%20https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

or for a overview you can follow

[link two](http://[1]:%20http://%20https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)